# Predicting a possible match to avoid using Levenshtein algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

My problem is, I have to scan a sequence of DNA with a given number of maximum substitutions, insertions and deletions.

For this, I have been able to modify the Levenshtein algorithm to determine this, that starts from each character in the sequence. But this is way to slow and I would like to know if there exists a way to predict that there is no possible match from each character so i can avoid the use of the Levenshtein algorithm and skip ahead to the next character in the sequence.

I need to evaluate as fast as possible that this match simply can't work

Is this possible or is there another way to handle this when I am iterating char by char through each sequence?

Example:

- Pattern: ATTATACA[1,1,1]
- Sequence: ATCGCACBTTATACATTATACAATCGCACBTTATACATTATACA

Comment: have a look at [Boyer Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)

Comment: I think you have two options: (1) speed up the existing algorithm or (2) parallelise it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to determine if the pattern `ATTATACA` exists in the other string? That the pattern `ATTATACA` or some variation of it with no more than N substitutions exists in the other string? Or if you can transform `ATTATACA` into the other string with some minimum number of substitutions?

Comment: I want to look for an exact pattern and its variations within separate values of substitutions, insertions and deletions.
In this case, i already have a Levenshtein algorithm that computes this. It is just to slow to run for a whole pattern at each character in the sequence

Comment: So given your edit, `GTATACAG`would match because it's one deletion (removal of the first `A`), one substitution (first `T` replaced by `G`), and one insertion (adding `G` at the end of the string)? Any combination of 0 or more additions, substitutions, and deletions up to the maximum is allowed?

Comment: Thats right.. Any combination up to the maximum is allowed. it can for example match to "AGTATACA" with only one substitution

Answer (score 0):

For single pattern there is Knuth-Morris-Prat algorithm. Of course it depends on the data but it's the fastest algorithm. For multiple pattern there is Aho-Corasick algorithm. You can try my implementation with php @ codeplex.com (phpahocorasick). It also allows a wildcard.

Comment: But Knuth-Morris-Pratt is for exact searching. I already have that implemented for those cases.